# Is there some kind of a SailsJS API adaptor on the front end for use with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

This is what I would like while creating my AngularJS app with a SailsJS API Backend:

- Ability on the client side (AngularJS) to create a Model which can perform all CRUD operations that a framework like SailsJS provides. So if I am making a TodoList App, say I have a model called todoItem. I would like it to have prototype methods like `save()`, `loadById()`, `delete()` etc. which internally hit the correct SailsJS API.
- I would also like the ability to have a standard querying capability which reaches all the way till SailsJS query engine.

My ultimate goal is to not have to write SailsJS API calls in a `services.js` file because most of the service calls I will write will be redundant specially when SailsJS scaffolds them for me in a clean way.

Is there a solution out there which achieves this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using $resource. 
for example:

```
var users = $resource(API_URL + 'user/:id',
        {id: '@id'}, {
            query: {method: 'GET'},
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        });
```

When creating a new instance of a user you can use:

```
user = new users();
user.name = 'John';
user.$save()
```

You can create custom functions, and in that function call the user.$save() to apply the changes.